# Chrome extension authenticating against O365 (Azure AD??)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, adal, adal.js

Doing some research here and it looks like if we have O365 without federation with our local AD that it may be called ["Azure Active Directory - Cloud Only"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/about-office-365-identity)

It also appears that from the extension we'll need to do an OAuth2 call to authenticate and follow the ["Non-Google account authentication"](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity)

Seems to be superhelpful (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) (I'm trying to find out why v1 is better for work accounts now ....)

A few questions ...

1. Did I misunderstand anything?
2. Related to #1 ... is it true that Azure will expose accounts as AD accounts if they are just for O365?
3. Any gotchas before I start slinging code?
4. What is the difference between [Azure OAuth2 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) and using [ADAL?](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)
5. Finally ... anyone know if I will be restricted from doing some of this in a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

Google provides the Chrome Identity API (exact method being `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`) to authenticate to any OAuth 2.0 provider using the Implicit Grant Flow.

On how to achieve this I answered on the following question: [Azure AD App Redirect URI for Chrome Exntension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396398/azure-ad-app-redirect-uri-for-chrome-exntension/62971054#62971054)