# Azure AD App Redirect URI for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using the [Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript (MSAL.js)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal) version `1.3.2` in my chrome extension built on React JS. I have two login scenario I need to support in order to get a bearer token used in the rest of my application:

1. `promptLogin()` handles the first time the user authenticates in my extension.
2. `getTokenAsync()` handles acquiring a bearer token silently for a user who has already authenticated in my extension. This approach returns an id token that I do not use, should I? Instead in my source code at the bottom of the post you'll see I call `promptLogin()` right after this to get the bearer token.

Both of these methods are called within the main `login()` method based if the user is authenticated or not. From the MSAL.js docs it seems like `redirectUri` is optional and authentication for my two scenarios works as expected in development environment on localhost without this property.

This property `redirectUri` seems to be required in production when the user interacts with the extension via Chrome or the new Microsoft Edge. I am not sure what the `redirectUri` would be in this case or if I even need one. I belive it should be formatted as `https://ihmmiapcpnfpphpdinbmjfglladedjoa.chromiumapp.org/`.

The flow I expect is when the the user clicks "LOG IN" for the first time my `promptLogin()` handles their request.

[image]

I log in with my account

[image]

Then get this error

[image]

Here's my app registration and the redirect URIs in Azure AD. "Supported Account types are: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)". I have also checked both "Access tokens" and "ID tokens" for the "To enable the implicit grant flow, select the tokens you would like to be issued by the authorization endpoint:".

[image]

This is my MSAL configuration.

```js
this.msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_MICROSOFT_GRAPH_CLIENT_ID,
        redirectUri: "https://ihmmiapcpnfpphpdinbmjfglladedjoa.chromiumapp.org/popup.html"
    },
};

this.msalInstance = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(this.msalConfig);
this.scopes = [
    "directory.accessasuser.all", 
    "directory.readwrite.all", 
    "user.readwrite.all"
];
```

The main login method.

```js
async login() {       
    if (this.msalInstance.getAccount()) {
        alert('authenticated');         
        const token = await this.getTokenAsync();
        return token;
        
    } else {
        alert('not authenticated please sign in');
        await this.promptLogin();
        const token = await this.getTokenAsync();
        return token;
    }        
}
```

Logic for my 2 scenarios based on if the user is authenticated or not.

```js
getTokenAsync() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let tokenRequest = {
            scopes: this.scopes
        };
        this.msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
        .then(response => {
            resolve(response.accessToken);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(`E: ${err}`);                
            if (err.name === "InteractionRequiredAuthError") {
                return this.msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
                    .then(response => {
                        resolve(response.accessToken);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.error(`E: ${err}`);
                        reject();
                    });
            }
        });
    });
}
promptLogin() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let loginRequest = {
            scopes: this.scopes
        };          
        this.msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(`res: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            resolve();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            alert(`E: ${err}`);
            console.error(`E: ${err}`);
            reject();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg, 
I have a similar setup and am having difficulties getting it to work. Did you figure out this?

Answer (score 4):

The protocol for chromium extensions is `chrome-extension://`, so I believe your redirect uri should be: `chrome-extension://ihmmiapcpnfpphpdinbmjfglladedjoa/popup.html`

Edit: In addition to using the above redirect URI format, you need to ensure the following:

1. The redirect URI is added to your application's redirect URIs in the Azure Portal (under "Mobile and desktop applications").
2. The page used for the redirect URI is included in the [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) section of your extension's `manifest.json`.

Comment: I get a `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` error instead saying "ihmmiapcpnfpphpdinbmjfglladedjoa is blocked Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension. Try disabling your extensions."

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by just simply using the Chrome Identity API as shown below:

```
var redirectUrl = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()

/*global chrome*/
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id or just 'common'>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?' +
      'response_type=token' +
      '&response_mode=fragment' +
      `&client_id=Azure AD Application Client ID` +
      `&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}` +
      '&scope=openid https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation profile',
    interactive: true
  },
  function (responseWithToken) {
      // the access token needs to be extracted from the response.
  }
);
```

Additionally, you need to add Identity to permissions in the manifest.js, which is well documented here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Comment: what i am doing wrong, if the login is done, but I do not get the token back in the responseWithToken? Inside this variable I just get the URL back, without token etc.

Comment: I don't know, there could be quite a few things wrong, from how you setup the Azure AD Application, to how you configured chrome. I'd suggest to open a new StackOverflow issue with all the info, and ping me here, I'll take a look