# Azure AD oauth on Chrome Extension using chrome.identity?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, azure-authentication

I'm seeking some help to understand  how to implement an azure oauth login on my chrome webextension. I've found a very [useful suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396398/azure-ad-app-redirect-uri-for-chrome-exntension/62971054#62971054) on SO by @Rinor how to use user.identity in with Azure authentication and I think I'm half way to succeed.

Using the code below I get the login popup and I can easily sign-in with username and password. As a response from Azure I get an url that contain the token, I then extranct the token with a regex and I save it to the crhorme.storage.

The problem is that I'm now stuck. How should I then proceed now to get the user details (I only need the email address or the username) actually. I do not understand if now I need another ajax call to /oauth2/v2.0/token to get an additional token...and if so, how should I pass the token I got from the initial call to /oauth2/v2.0/authorize.

Does anyone have any idea on how to proceed? Any help would be more than welcome

Thanks a lot in advance

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant_id + '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?' + // <= here tenant id or just common
      'response_type=token' +
      '&response_mode=fragment' +
      '&prompt=login' +
      '&client_id=' + client_id + // <= here client id from azure console
      '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUrl +
      '&scope=openid https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation profile',
    interactive: true
  },
  function (responseWithToken) {
    // the access token needs to be extracted from the response.
    console.log(responseWithToken);

    let token = responseWithToken.match(/(?<=access_token=).*(?=&token_type)/);
    chrome.storage.local.set({ "azure_token": token }, function () {
      console.log('Value is set');
    });
  }
);

// What next? :S
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the username of the user, you could decode the `access_token` what is the response after the user login. And the `upn` in the claims is the username of the user, maybe a phone number, email address, or unformatted string.

For more details about access token, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens).

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the meanwhile I was able to set up the implicit grant flow using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow and it works like a charm. I get the token in the callback url and I extract it via regex. Then I use it in the ajax headers to call the apis and it works. I'm still figuring out how to refresh it before expires...

Comment: Hi @Mauro are you still looking for any help on this

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity thanks for your message. I would say now I am confident with the flow itself, I use it successfully with Azure and other providers, however, I am struggling to understand where the credentials are being stored. This is a real mystery. when I install the extension the flow is triggered, I then insert the credentials and I get a valid token in the redirect URL. When then I trigger again the flow to get a new token, I get a valid token without being asked for credentials at all and there is nothing stored in chrome://identity-internals

Comment: As you can see in the [document](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#getAuthToken-caching) Chrome has an in-memory cache of access tokens until the token expiry/change in password you can get a new token without provinding the credentials

Comment: No unfortunately this is not true. The in memory cache works only for google tokens retrieved via getAuthToken. The token obtained from 3rd party authorities via the launchWebAuthFlow are not stored in chrome://identity-internals...but at the same time the credentials are stored somewhere, the question is where...